# How to echo json response object value

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

i want to echo the stock_quantity of the json response array.

```
Array ( 
    [Status] => OK 
    [Result] => {"Cookie":"Cookie value","Data":{"Wquantity":[{"ITEMCODE":"Item_1","Stock_Quantity":3.0000000},{"ITEMCODE":"Item_2","Stock_Quantity":50.0000000}]},"Messages":[]} 
    [Error] => 
    [ErrorCode] => 
    [Benchmark] => 0 
)
```

I try with

```
echo $decoded->{'Result'}->{'Data'}
```

but is not working

Comment: have you tried ``` echo $decoded['Result']['Data']['Wquantity'][0]['Stock_Quantity'] ```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$decoded` is an array, not an object, so you should be using `$decoded['Result']`.

`$decoded['Result']` is a JSON string, so you need to decode it before you can access the contents.

The `Data` property is an object, so you won't be able to echo it, you should use `var_dump()`.

```
$result = json_decode($decoded['Result']);
var_dump($result->Data);
```